# Pandas .str.extract is not working on string

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, extract

I have  cells with content like this:

{'Code': 'YewrH', 'Owner': 'yyy.xxx@cccc.com', 'Environment_Type': 'Prod', 'ID': '23000', 'InfoSeC': 'Internal', 'PDDA': 'Basic', 'Level': 'Basic', 'Contact': 'czcxc.zxcxc@yyy.com'}

The cells are in a column called tags. So i try:

```
    tmp['tags'].str.extract(r'ID\':\s\'(\d*)\'', expand=True)
```

I expect to get the regular expression to return 23000 but the only information i get back is: NaN. Can someone please help?

I found that this works:
         tmp['tags'] = tmp['tags'].astype(str)
         tmp['APM_id'] = tmp['tags'].str.extract(r'ID\':\s\'(\d*)\'', expand=True)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using an escape character for `:`. Simply do,

```
tmp['tags'].str.extract(r'ID\'\:\s\'(\d*)\'')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have bigger problems than that and I cannot figure it out. For some reason no regular expression at all works. I wonder if there can be something with the data type. I have problems to do other "operations" on these cells. I don't know Python that well bit it sometimes say something like "non hashable" ...

Comment: If i converted the column to string it worked like expected....